# my website shows 500 internal server error , when receiving ajax response

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

It shows 500 internal server error when retrieving data through ajax. But the whole code works well in my localhost. And i am facing this error for the first time, so i am not sure whether this error is caused due to fetching data through AJAX. If it is not the correct reason please get me the correct reason.
this is my coding

```
$.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"api_fle/get_post",
            data:{u_id:u_id,type:'all13'},
            success:function(response){             
                if(response!=0){    
                    var parsed = $.parseJSON(response);
                    date = new Array();
                    events = new Array();

                    $.each(parsed,function(i,parsed){
                        if(parsed.shred.length>15){var shred=jQuery.trim(parsed.shred).substring(0, 14) + '...';} else{var shred=parsed.shred;}
                        if(parsed.cmpny_name == parsed.shred){var sharedd=parsed.cmpny_name; var sha=""; var pic=parsed.pro_pic;}else{var sharedd=shred; var sha=' shared <a href="page.php?us_id='+parsed.u_id+'" style="color:#fff;"><input type="hidden" id="who_hid_id" value="'+parsed.id+'">'+parsed.cmpny_name+"</a>'s Event"; var pic=parsed.pic;}
                        date[i]=parsed.SharedDate;
                        events[i]='<div class="col-md-10 post" style="background:#FFF"><span class="company-logo-small"><img src="'+pic+'" style=" width: 60px; height: 60px;"></span>'
                        +'<span class="fullhead"><span class="posted-name"><a id="who_shred" style="color:#fff;cursor:pointer;"><input type="hidden" id="who_hid_id" value="'+parsed.id+'"><span itemprop="hiringOrganization">'+sharedd+'</span></a>'+sha+'</span></span>'
                        +'<span class="post-status" style="color:#fff;">'+prettyDate(parsed.SharedDate)+'</span><div class="post-inner"><div class="col-md-12"><div class="panel panel-default event">'
                        +'<div class="panel-heading title">'+parsed.name+'</div><ul class="list-group"><li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>'+parsed.location+'</li>'
                        +'<li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>'+parsed.date+'</li><li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>'+parsed.time+'</li>'
                        +'<li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-users"></i>Attendees '+parsed.attendies+'</li></ul><ul class="list-group"><div class="panel-body"><p>'+parsed.decs+'</p>'
                        +'<a class="btn btn-xs btn-info pull-left" target="_blank" href="eventview?evnt_id='+parsed.evnt_id+'">View</a>&nbsp&nbsp'
                        +'<a href="pagelink?evnt_id='+parsed.evnt_id+'" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-facebook-square" style="font-size:20px;"></i></a>'
                        +'<a class="twitter popup" href="pagelink?evnt_id='+parsed.evnt_id+'" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-twitter-square " style="font-size:20px;"></i></a>'
                        +'<a class="twitter popup" href="pagelink?evnt_id='+parsed.evnt_id+'" target="_blank">'
                        +'<i class="fa fa-fw fa-linkedin-square" style="font-size:20px;"></i></a><a class="twitter popup" href="pagelink?evnt_id='+parsed.evnt_id+'" target="_blank">'
                        +'<i class="fa fa-fw fa-google-plus" style="font-size:20px;"></i></a></div></ul><div id="img"></div><div class="clearfix"></div></div></div></div></div>'; 
                    });


                }
                });

-------------------------               
page : get_post             
--------------------
if($_POST['type']=='all13'){   
    $update_time=mysql_query("UPDATE `share_post` SET `sharedDate`='".$_POST['time']."' WHERE `frm_id` = 'U005114608238'");

     $sql=select_query("SELECT s.id,e.u_id,e.cmpny_name,n.pro_pic as pic,l.pro_pic,l.level as lv,m.evnt_id,m.name,m.location,m.decs,m.time,
    m.date,m.attendies,s.frm_id,s.is_important,s.shred,s.SharedDate,s.lvl FROM employer_info e,login l,login n,`event` m, share_post s WHERE n.u_id=s.frm_id and e.u_id=l.u_id and m.u_id=l.u_id and m.evnt_id=s.post_id and s.to_id='".$_POST['u_id']."' order by s.id desc"); 
$count=count($sql);
    $response=array(); 
       for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
                    array_push($response,$sql[$i]);
                                }   
                                echo json_encode($response);            
                                  }
```

when i have inspected the error , i got something like in this screenshot

Comment: Please share you code.

Comment: Check error logs for the actual error.

Comment: the reason is that, the condition is different from servers to servers. Most of the code does not run on live servers but run on localhost. Please provide your code, so that we can identify which function or code is not working on live server.

Comment: You just assume that your sql calls work, I do not see any error handling. `select_query` is a function you created, we have no idea what it does. But, if it does not do error handling either, then you are in trouble.

Comment: Also, your code is open to sql injection and uses the deprecated MySQL extension to access the database.

Comment: select_query is my own function to execute my mysql query.

Comment: how can i prevent sql injection , and can you explain what is mean by deprecated MySQL extension to access the database

Comment: @APARNNAMS it's no use to try and explain to you, you have to learn to use google. just type "mysql deprecated php" and you will be directed to thousands (literally **thousands**) of tutorials, articles and documentation pages explaining all there is to learn about that topic. You have to try and do a bit of the work by yourself, not just depend on others to do it for you.